# How do I get the year of a DateTime object in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract the year from a DateTime variable in Perl.

I have tried this:

```
% cat test2
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use DateTime;

my $dt_begin = DateTime->new(
        year    => 2000,
        month   => 1,
        day     => 1,
);

print "###\n$dt_begin $dt_begin->year\n###\n";
```

And I get this as output:

```
% ./test2
###
2000-01-01T00:00:00 2000-01-01T00:00:00->year
###
```

While I was expecting:

```
% ./test2
###
2000-01-01T00:00:00 2000
###
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`year()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Eyear()) is a method and method calls aren't interpolated. You can use concatenation:

```
...
print("###\n$dt_begin " . $dt_begin->year() . "\n###\n");
...
```

Or [`printf()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html):

```
...
printf("###\n%s %i\n###\n", $dt_begin, $dt_begin->year());
...
```